# How to compare string and bytes32 in an optimal way?

Tags: string, keccak, bytes32

I have keccak256 `string` encrypt in blockchain and keccak256(decrypt) `bytes` in function.

This code works well. I pass an unencrypted string to the function and check it for validity.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Hello {

    // keccak256: hello
    string encrypt = "1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8";

    // How to check?: encrypt == keccak256(decrypt)
    // check("hello") => true
    // Can this check be done in a better way?

    function check(string calldata decrypt) public view returns(bool) {
        bytes32 key1 = keccak256(abi.encode(bytes32ToString(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(decrypt)))));
        bytes32 key2 = keccak256(abi.encode(encrypt));
        
        if (key1 == key2) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function bytes32ToString(bytes32 _bytes32) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        uint8 i = 0;
        bytes memory bytesArray = new bytes(64);
        for (i = 0; i < bytesArray.length; i++) {

            uint8 _f = uint8(_bytes32[i/2] & 0x0f);
            uint8 _l = uint8(_bytes32[i/2] >> 4);

            bytesArray[i] = toByte(_l);
            i = i + 1;
            bytesArray[i] = toByte(_f);
        }
        return string(bytesArray);
    }

    function toByte(uint8 _uint8) internal pure returns (bytes1) {
        if(_uint8 < 10) {
            return bytes1(_uint8 + 48);
        } else {
            return bytes1(_uint8 + 87);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: remix]

I don't think this is the optimal code.

Comment: You can save a lot of gas by storing encrypt as a `bytes32` instead of `string`. Is that an option for you ?

Comment: @hroussille Thank you for your comment. I think I need to store in a string variable.

Comment: May I ask why ?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR : You're overdoing it a bit, haha.

You don't need to store encrypt as a string.

```
bytes32 key1 = keccak256(abi.encode(bytes32ToString(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(decrypt))))); 
bytes32 key2 = keccak256(abi.encode(encrypt));
```

Here you're turning the decrypt string into bytes32 (using keccak), then converting to a string so it matches encrypt, then turning it into bytes32 again with keccak. If you stored encrypt as bytes32 directly, you could avoid that intermediary step, saving you gas on storage (because bytes32 takes up less space than a string) AND on execution.

Note that re-hashing them is completely useless too. You could  simply have

```
// keccak256: hello
bytes32 encrypt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("hello")); // Obviously you'd store the result directly to avoid showing the answer in plain text, but this is just so you get the idea. 

function check(string calldata decrypt) public view returns(bool){
  bytes32 key = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(decrypt); 
  if(key == encrypt) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
```